# Function whose all first-order partial derivatives are the same

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

Let $f:\mathbb R^m\rightarrow\mathbb R$ be a sufficiently differentiable function and suppose that there is a function $g:\mathbb R^m\rightarrow\mathbb R$ such that $$ D_if=g,\quad i=1,2,\dots,m,\qquad(\ast), $$where $g$ *does not have an index*, i.e. it is the same for all values of $i$, and $D_i$ is the partial derivative with respect to the $i$th argument. What can we tell about the functional dependency of $f$ on its variables?

Let $h:\mathbb R^m\rightarrow\mathbb R$ be given by $h(x)=\sum_{i=1}^mx_i$, and $q:\mathbb R\rightarrow\mathbb R$ is any (sufficiently well behaved) function, then $f=q\circ h$ satisfies $$ D_if=q^\prime\circ h, $$so such a choice of $f$ solves $(\ast)$ the equation with $g=q^\prime\circ h$.

I suspect that *all* solutions of $(\ast)$ are of this form, but I am unable to prove it. Am I correct in this? If so, how to prove it?